# CSS transitions for expanding search box

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use CSS transitions along with simple jQuery `toggleClass` to achieve the expanding search input effect.

My attempt has been mildly successful but still far from how I want it to be.

I have made a JSFiddle of what I have achieved so far: 
https://jsfiddle.net/3jhr24u3/

This is a GIF of what I want to achieve exactly:

[image: GIF screen of what I want to achieve]

My HTML(as in JSFIDDLE):

```
<form class="search-box pull-right" action="#" method="post">
    <span class="icon-magnifier search-icon"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/30_Free_Black_ToolBar_Icons/40/Black_Search.png" alt="Search" /></span>
    <input type="text" name="search-bar" class="search-bar" />
</form>
```

My CSS(as in the JSFIDDLE):

```
.search-box {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 400px;
}
.search-icon {
    font-size: 1.875em;
    color: #1CB6B5;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.search-icon-open {
    z-index: 1000;
    color: #FFF;
    left: -290px;
}
.search-bar {
    background: #1cb6b5;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    width: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.search-bar-open {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's a demo I modified to better suit what your looking for http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/avzrLE. it's a start that you can play around with.

Comment: Avoid floats to layouts. Floats are for floating, not for layouts. Your float left forbidden you to animate properly. @Harry answer is correct, read it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to to is absolutely position the search icon with respect to the parent at `right: 0px` and change it to `right: 400px` (width of the search bar) when clicked on.

If you don't want the search icon to be aligned with the right side of the page then you can nullify the `margin-left` on the parent form and add a `width` depending on the needs.

```
.search-icon {
    font-size: 1.875em;
    color: #1CB6B5;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.search-icon-open {
    z-index: 1000;
    color: #FFF;
    right: 400px;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3jhr24u3/5/) (Stack Snippet is not working as library is not getting loaded. Not sure if it is just for me).